# Changing the connecting point of an AutoLayout constraint?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have the following setup within my app. There is a footer bar that has a number of buttons on, above that there is a `UIImageView` that currently has the constraints set to 10,10,10,10 for all edges. I have added an image below to show the constraint.

[image]

Now what I would like to do is when a button on the footer bar is clicked a new "sub bar" will appear between the footer bar and the `UIImageView`. My question is how do I adjust the constraint so that the bottom anchor is connected to the new sub bar and not the footer. In a sense it pushes the `UIImageView` up to make way for the new bar?

I don't want the new bar to go over the `UIImageVIew`, instead I want to push it up with an animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create that bar between the imageview and the footer and layout it properly then make its height constarint = 0 to be hidden at first, then control darg this constarint as `IBOutlet` and when you want to show change its constant to say 100 and call:

```
[self.view layoutIfNeed];
```

Put it in a `UIView` animation if you want it animated.

Comment: Sorry should have said that there will be multiple bars of different types so I will be adding them programatically.

Comment: Ok , make the middle view in storyboard as I said and create any number of bars as you want and add them as subviews hooked properly from top to bottom

Comment: I've actually taken your answer as is and I have added a "wrapper" view and set that to 0. I just add/change the content into that and adjust the constraint as you have said.

Comment: Hope it helps . . .